# dlmパッケージによる状態空間モデル

Tags: r

Rでdlmパッケージを用いて状態空間モデルによる時系列予測を試みていますがエラーが出て通りません。
http://logics-of-blue.com/%E5%AD%A3%E7%AF%80%E3%81%A8%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89/
を参考に取り組んでいます。

```
#　Step2
#　MLEでパラメタ推定。
fit.5 <- dlmMLE(tm,parm=dlmMLE(tm,parm=c(0,1,1,1),build.5,method="Nelder-
Mead")$par,build.5,method="BFGS")
```

の部分ですが、

```
test.data
```

の部分を自分のデータ

```
tm<-hoge$hoge
```

に変えてやってみたのですが、次のエラーが出て通りません。

```
Inconsistent dimensions of arguments
```

次元があっていない?とのことですが、どこが原因なのでしょうか。parm=c(0,1,1,1)のあたりでしょうか?ちなみにダブルクオーテーションは全て半角に置換しました。データの型はnumericです。

実行結果です。

```
Browse[1]> #　Step2
Browse[1]> #　MLEでパラメタ推定。
Browse[1]> fit.5 <-dlmMLE(tm,parm=dlmMLE(tm,parm=c(0,1,1,1),build.5,
method="Nelder-Mead")$par,build.5,method="BFGS")
Error during wrapup: Inconsistent dimensions of arguments
```

Comment: 例えばですが、`dlmMLE(1,parm=dlmMLE(1,parm=c(0,1,1,1),build.5,...` などとしてもエラーが発生しますか？

Comment: 1に変えても同じエラーが出ました。